# Data repeats itself when trying to crawl html data into csv with python

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl data from a table divided in multiple webpages and transfering this data to a csv. The csv must contain the csv must contain every data under the columns "Palavra" and "Divisão Silábica" separated by commas. The website is http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=syllables&act=list&letter=a&start=0.

Following the argument structure they have for their links, my code adds 100 (the maximum amount of rows a single webpage shows) every time it crawls data and when these are done it goes to the next letter.

```
abc = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
"s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

with open("divisao_silabica.csv", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    file.write("palavra,tipo,divisao_silabica\n")

    for letra in abc:
        hundred = 0
        seguintes = True

        while seguintes:
            r = requests.get('http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=syllables&act=list&letter='+letra+"&start="+str(hundred))
            data = r.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
            rows = soup.find(id="rollovertable").find_all("tr")

            for row in rows:
                cells = row.find_all("td")
                if cells:
                    palavra = cells[0].find('b').find('a').get_text()
                    divisaosilabica = cells[1].get_text()
                    file.write(f"{palavra}, {divisaosilabica}\n")

            hundred += 100
            seguintes = "seguintes" in soup.get_text()
```

When I checked the output, the separator commas were not showing for some reason. When I looked closely, I noticed commas appear, but when they do, the whole table data follows. Between the data scraped from the row "a-pedido" and the row "a-propósito", for instance, there is a BUNCH of trash, which data in the whole table.

> a-pedido, a-pe·di·do
>
> a-propósito (nome masculino) a-pro·pó·si·to a-tempo (nome masculino)
> a-tem·po à-toa (adjetivo) à-to·a à-toinha (adjetivo) à-to·i·nha
> à-vontade (nome masculino) à-von·ta·de aa (nome feminino) a·a aabora
> (nome feminino) a·a·bo·ra aacheniano (nome masculino) aa·che·ni·a·no
> aacheniano (adjetivo) aa·che·ni·a·no aal (nome masculino) a·al
> aaleniano (adjetivo) a·a·le·ni·a·no aaleniense (adjetivo)
> aa·le·ni·en·se aaleniense (nome masculino) aa·le·ni·en·se aaleniense
> (nome feminino) aa·le·ni·en·se aalênio (nome masculino) a·a·lê·ni·o
> aalénio (nome masculino) a·a·lé·ni·o
>
> aarônico (adjetivo) a·a·rô·ni·co aarónico (adjetivo) a·a·ró·ni·co
>
> aarônida (nome masculino) a·a·rô·ni·da aarônida (adjetivo)
> a·a·rô·ni·da aarônida (nome feminino) a·a·rô·ni·da aarónida (adjetivo)
> a·a·ró·ni·da
>
> aarónida (nome masculino) a·a·ró·ni·da
>
> aarónida (nome feminino) a·a·ró·ni·da
>
> aaronita (nome masculino) a·a·ro·ni·ta
>
> ab-reação (nome feminino) ab-re·a·ção ab-reativo (adjetivo)
> ab-re·a·ti·vo ab-repticiamente (advérbio) ab-rep·ti·ci·a·men·te
> ab-reptício (adjetivo) ab-rep·tí·ci·o ab-rogação (nome feminino)
> ab-ro·ga·ção ab-rogado (adjetivo) ab-ro·ga·do ab-rogador (adjetivo)
> ab-ro·ga·dor ab-rogador (nome masculino) ab-ro·ga·dor ab-rogamento
> (nome masculino) ab-ro·ga·men·to
>
> ab-rogante (nome masculino) ab-ro·gan·te
>
> ab-rogante (nome feminino) ab-ro·gan·te
>
> ab-rogante (adjetivo) ab-ro·gan·te
>
> ab-rogar (verbo) ab-ro·gar ab-rogativo (adjetivo) ab-ro·ga·ti·vo
> ab-rogatório (adjetivo) ab-ro·ga·tó·ri·o ab-rogável (adjetivo)
> ab-ro·gá·vel aba (nome masculino) a·ba aba (nome feminino) a·ba ababá
> (nome masculino) a·ba·bá ababá (nome feminino) a·ba·bá ababá
> (adjetivo) a·ba·bá ababalhado (adjetivo) a·ba·ba·lha·do ababalhar
> (verbo) a·ba·ba·lhar ababelado (adjetivo) a·ba·be·la·do ababelar
> (verbo) a·ba·be·lar ababosado (adjetivo) a·ba·bo·sa·do ababosar
> (verbo) a·ba·bo·sar abacá (nome masculino) a·ba·cá abacalhoadamente
> (advérbio) a·ba·ca·lho·a·da·men·te
>
> abacalhoado (adjetivo) a·ba·ca·lho·a·do abacalhoar (verbo)
> a·ba·ca·lho·ar abacamartado (adjetivo) a·ba·ca·mar·ta·do abaçanado
> (adjetivo) a·ba·ça·na·do abaçanar (verbo) a·ba·ça·nar abacanto (nome
> masculino) a·ba·can·to
>
> abacate (adjetivo) a·ba·ca·te abacate (nome masculino) a·ba·ca·te
> abacate (nome feminino) a·ba·ca·te abacateira (nome feminino)
> a·ba·ca·tei·ra abacateiro (nome masculino) a·ba·ca·tei·ro abacaxi
> (adjetivo) a·ba·ca·xi abacaxi (nome masculino) a·ba·ca·xi abacaxi
> (nome feminino) a·ba·ca·xi abacelado (adjetivo) a·ba·ce·la·do
> abacelamento (nome masculino) a·ba·ce·la·men·to abacelar (verbo)
> a·ba·ce·lar abacelável (adjetivo) a·ba·ce·lá·vel abacenino (adjetivo)
> a·ba·ce·ni·no abacenino (nome masculino) a·ba·ce·ni·no abacense
> (adjetivo) a·ba·cen·se abacense (nome masculino) a·ba·cen·se abacense
> (nome feminino) a·ba·cen·se abacharelado (adjetivo) a·ba·cha·re·la·do
> abacharelar (verbo) a·ba·cha·re·lar abacial (adjetivo) a·ba·ci·al
> abacinado (adjetivo) a·ba·ci·na·do
>
> abacinamento (nome masculino) a·ba·ci·na·men·to abacinar (verbo)
> a·ba·ci·nar abacisco (nome masculino) a·ba·cis·co
>
> abacista (nome masculino) a·ba·cis·ta abacista (nome feminino)
> a·ba·cis·ta ábaco (nome masculino) á·ba·co abacomitato (nome
> masculino) a·ba·co·mi·ta·to
>
> abacómite (nome masculino) a·ba·có·mi·te
>
> abacômite (nome masculino) a·ba·cô·mi·te abacto (nome masculino)
> a·bac·to abactor (nome masculino) a·bac·tor abáculo (nome masculino)
> a·bá·cu·lo abada (nome feminino) a·ba·da abadado (nome masculino)
> a·ba·da·do
>
> a-propósito, a-pro·pó·si·to

It seems like I got the html structure right? Inside the table, element by id "rollovertable", there are multiple rows tr that contain cells td. If that is right, I guess there might be something wrong with my iteration syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code as-is is that the HTML is not well formed and the standard parser, `html.parser`, you pass to BeautifulSoup cannot cope with how bad it is.

Consider this snippet:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
table = soup.find(id="rollovertable")

rows = table.find_all("tr")
print(f"rows: {len(rows)}")

for i, row in enumerate(rows, start=1):
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    print(f"row {i}: cells: {len(cells)}")
```

and you get something like:

```
rows: 101
row 1: cells: 200
row 2: cells: 200
row 3: cells: 198
...
row 97: cells: 10
row 98: cells: 8
row 99: cells: 6
row 100: cells: 4
row 101: cells: 2
```

Probably not what you were expecting.  If you [install `html5lib`](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) and use that as the parser in BS:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")
```

you get what you probably thought you were going to get:

```
rows: 101
row 1: cells: 0
row 2: cells: 2
row 3: cells: 2
...
row 97: cells: 2
row 98: cells: 2
row 99: cells: 2
row 100: cells: 2
row 101: cells: 2
```

I explored the parser options because I looked at the raw HTML coming back from the server and could see nothing was terminated, all the cells were essentially nesting inside each other.

You can see the pros/cons of each parser [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).  What caught my eye about html5lib was "Creates valid HTML5".

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to get all the [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) elements :

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import pandas as pd

URL = "http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?" \
      "action=syllables&act=list&letter={}&start={}"

ID = {"id": "rollovertable"} # table's id

NLET = 3 # use None if all letters needed
N100 = 2 # the number of hundreds (optional)

tables = {}
for letter in ascii_lowercase[:NLET]:
    not_empty = True; start = 100
    while not_empty and (start<=100*N100):
    # while not_empty: # uncomment if all hundreds needed
        tmp_df = pd.read_html(URL.format(letter, start), attrs=ID)[0]
        tables[(letter, start)] = tmp_df
        not_empty = not tmp_df.empty
        start = start+100
```

And to make the (`.csv`), you can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)/[`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
df = (pd.concat(tables, names=["letter", "start", "index"])
          .set_axis(["palavra", "divisao_silabica"], axis=1))

# or to preserve the original header and ignore the letter/start/index
# df = pd.concat(tables, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(
    "divisao_silabica.csv",
    index=False, # to ignore letter/start/index
    sep=",", # by default
)
```

Output (*of* `divisao_silabica`) :

```
palavra,divisao_silabica
abadágio (nome masculino),a·ba·dá·gi·o
abadalado (adjetivo),a·ba·da·la·do
abadalar (verbo),a·ba·da·lar
abadalhocado (adjetivo),a·ba·da·lho·ca·do
...
cáboco (nome masculino),cá·bo·co
cabograma (nome masculino),ca·bo·gra·ma
caboje (nome masculino),ca·bo·je
cabole (nome masculino),ca·bo·le
cabolocosso (nome masculino),ca·bo·lo·cos·so
cabomba (nome feminino),ca·bom·ba
```

Preview (*of* `df`):

```
print(df.reset_index().to_string(
      index=False, max_rows=10, show_dimensions=True))

letter  start  index                       palavra  divisao_silabica
     a    100      0     abadágio (nome masculino)      a·ba·dá·gi·o
     a    100      1          abadalado (adjetivo)     a·ba·da·la·do
     a    100      2              abadalar (verbo)       a·ba·da·lar
     a    100      3       abadalhocado (adjetivo) a·ba·da·lho·ca·do
     a    100      4 abadalhocado (nome masculino) a·ba·da·lho·ca·do
   ...    ...    ...                           ...               ...
     c    200     95    cabograma (nome masculino)      ca·bo·gra·ma
     c    200     96       caboje (nome masculino)          ca·bo·je
     c    200     97       cabole (nome masculino)          ca·bo·le
     c    200     98  cabolocosso (nome masculino)   ca·bo·lo·cos·so
     c    200     99       cabomba (nome feminino)         ca·bom·ba

[600 rows x 5 columns]
```